# Problems faced while scraping webpages in Python

Tags: python

So, I wrote a minimal function to scrape all the text from a webpage:

```
url = 'http://www.brainpickings.org'
request = requests.get(url)
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(request.content)
texts = soup_data.findAll(text=True)

def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
        return False

    return True
print filter(visible,texts)
```

But, it doesn't work that smooth. There are still unnecessary tags that are there. Also, if I try to to do a reg-ex removal of various characters that I don't want, I get an

```
error     elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 209: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thus, how can I improve this a bit more to make it better?

Comment: English meaning nazi: "scrapping" is the process of turning a car into scrap metal; to discard or remove from service. You probably meant "scraping, to scrape", to remove an outer layer with a tool. Corrected your post for you :-)

Comment: Do not use Regex for HTML parsing, see [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/851737).

Comment: Use [splinter zope](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/drivers/zope.testbrowser.html) .Easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [lxml](http://lxml.de/) this is pretty easy:

```
from lxml import html

doc = html.fromstring(content)
print doc.text_content()
```

**Edit**: Filtering the head could be done as follows:

```
print doc.body.text_content()
```